# How to call a generic with restrictions when type is known only at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I would like to have a class that handles population of lists of data from a drop down that can take any type as I would rather have the external code looking like:

```
listProvider.For<AnEnumType>().And<AClass>.GetLists();
```

than

```
listProvider.ForEnum<AnEnumType>().ForClass<AClass>.GetLists();
```

Here is the example code

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething<T>
    {
        if(typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
           //Do Something
        } else if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        {
           var bar = new Bar();

           //Problem How to call bar as type T must be a reference type?
           bar.GetData<T>()
        }     
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public IProvideList<T> GetData() where T : class
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}

public interface IProvideList<T> T : class
{

}
```

At compile time the complier doesn't know that T is a class, but I know it will at runtime. I can call this with reflection:

```
bar.GetType().GetMethod("GetData").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
```

however, I can't cast the result back to (IProvideList) when invoking the method because T must be a referenceType

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You haven't shown what you *need* the return type for - that will affect the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get around this by doing reflection:

```
bar.GetType().GetMethod("GetData").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
```

Then not attempting to cast the result, but accessing all methods and functions I required for the result via reflection to so:

```
var listProviderType = typeof (IProvideList<>).MakeGenericType(typeof (T));                    
var result = istProviderImplType.GetMethod("MethodINeedToCall").Invoke(listProviderImpl, null);
```

Not exactly the nicest code I know but it achieves the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `Bar` you can use `Bar<T>` and it all falls naturally to:

```
public void DoSomething<T>
{
    if(typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
       //Do Something
    } 
    else if (typeof(T).IsClass)
    {
       //Here you know T
       var bar = new Bar<T>();
       bar.GetData()
    }     
}

....
public class Bar<T>
{
    public IProvideList<T> GetData<T>() where T : class
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work as you'll have to pass the type when calling GetData on Bar<T>, which will result in the same problem.

Comment: Why? You know the type: it is the same T you pass into DoSomething<T>() method.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use `where T : class` in bar? if not try this.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething<T>()
    {
        if(typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
           //Do Something
        } else if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        {
           var bar = new Bar();

           //Problem How to call bar as type T must be a reference type?
            bar.GetData<T>();
        }     
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public IProvideList<T> GetData<T>() //where T : class
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}

public interface IProvideList<T> //where T : class
{

}
```

Comment: That would be the simpliest solution, however I can't do that in my case as the implentation of T is going to get an NHibernate session and call session.QueryOver<T>() which is needs the T to be a class. I didn't mention that because my question was really about generic and didn't want it being confused with NHibernate issues.